# parsedtime to timestamp using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

Recently I received some data with epoch timeparse. After taking it to timestamp using pandas, I noticed that the year returned is 1970, but the data is from around 2018 videogame stats.

I tried

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.creationTime, inferdatetime_format=True)

df['date'].describe()

count 51490
unique 51052
top 1970-01-01 00:25:04.380431622
freq 3
first 1970-01-01 00:24:56.891694922
last 1970-01-01 00:25:04.707332198
Name: date, dtype: object
```

the provider says the time unit is seconds but, for example for

```
1504279457970   

pd.to_datetime(1504279457970, infer_datetime_format=True)
Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:25:04.279457970')
```

and

```
pd.to_datetime(1504279457970, unit = 's')
...
OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'
```

Em'i doing something wrong?

I'm new to Python, so I don't know if I'm being naive.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `1504279457970` is not missing a floating point? If you do manual conversion, it is year **47700**, which is why the error is called `OutofBounds`

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the timestamp was given to you in ms precision. As you've shown, trying to convert the timestamp to a datetime using second precision results in the `OutOfBoundsDatetime` error. If you assume that the timestamp has a precision of milliseconds then you get a date in 2017 which is more likely.

It appears that pandas was guessing that you were using nanosecond precise timestamps when you supplied the method with the `inferdatetime_format=True` argument.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1504279457970, unit = 's')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'
>>> pd.to_datetime(1504279457970, unit = 'ms')
Timestamp('2017-09-01 15:24:17.970000')
>>> pd.to_datetime(1504279457970, unit = 'ns')
Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:25:04.279457970')
```

Comment: Thank you! :) it was in ms and not in s .